# Group Policy Management about:security_mmc

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

In Group Policy Management, when I click on an existing GPO, I get an Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration messaged that "about:security_mmc.exe" is not a trusted site.

[image: Error received when selecting a GPO]

It happens every time I click a different GPO. I read to add this to the trusted site list, which I did. I confirmed it is in the policy when I do gpresult.

[image: GPResult]

But I'm still getting this message. Anything else I need to do so this doesn't keep popping up?

Comment: That usually means the host has Internet Explorer protected mode enabled.

Comment: @GregAskew There should be a way to have protected mode enabled and not have this pop up. In an environment where I was not involved the the Domain level configuration, I do not get this problem on servers that have protected mode enabled.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you use *Site to Zone Assignment List* in a (computer) GPO: everything else is blocked including the built-in ones, and you cannot see the list.

I have to do some test to pinpoint exactly where this comes from but long story short: prefer using (user-side) Zone mapping GPO that is simply adding registry entries.

JJStellato's answer from [this social TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0baa6428-bf48-4e8a-82e1-b961918090d9/how-to-add-trusted-sites-to-group-policy) helped me figure it out. As well as the last reply from Alan Burchill.

[Microsoft - IE security zones registry entries for advanced users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/security-privacy/ie-security-zones-registry-entries)

[Microsoft - IE Enhanced Security Configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/dd883248(v=ws.10))

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has just spent a half a day researching and doing things like monitoring processes and the registry wondering why the *Site to Zone Assignment List* GPO was not applying to servers with IE Enhanced Security Configuration on, I may have found a solution. We always use the Computer Settings part of the GPO to force it on the entire computer/server (we do not use the User Settings unless it needs to be applied to specific groups of users. In this case, this policy in our organization needs to apply to devices.)

We don't turn off the IE Enhanced Security Configuration (IE ESC) on any of our servers and I was determined to find a solution.

After monitoring the registry/process explorer and wading through that, I discovered the problem.

When you set the *Site to Zone Assignment List*, it writes this information in the registry to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains
```

If IE ESC is off, when you go to:

```
Control Panel
  ->Internet Options
    ->Security tab
      ->Trusted Sites zone
        ->Sites button
```

you will see the sites listed there.

If IE ESC is on, the same location in the Control Panel above yields a blank list, as another response pointed out.

The problem is when IE ESC is on, I found that it *does not* use the registry location above. It reads from this location instead:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains
```

(The registry key is prefixed with *Esc*.) There appears to be no way to fix this in policy - however, this problem can simply be solved by manually writing a registry entry or, in the case of policies, I added an entry under:

```
Computer Configuration->Preferences->Windows Settings->Registry
```

that looks like this:

```
Preferences
  Registry
    about (Order: 1)
      General
         Action: Update 
           Properties
           Hive:       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
           Key path:   SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains\security_mmc.exe 
           Value name: about 
           Value type: REG_DWORD 
           Value data: 0x2 (2) 

      Common
        Options
          Stop processing items on this extension if an error occurs on this item: No 
          Remove this item when it is no longer applied: No 
          Apply once and do not reapply: No
```

With this added entry to our exiting policy with the settings in *Site to Zone Assignment List*, I have pushed this out to all of our servers, and now with IE ESC mode on, it shows up under the *Sites* list under *Trusted Sites* as it should - and it behaves how it should.

No more warnings when working on/viewing policies!

Dan

Answer (score 0):

When you say you added it to trusted sites, did you add it within the GPO only or manually on the server itself? If you added it via GPO, it may take some time to replicate to that server.

You can run rsop.msc to check your applied group policies.

You can check IE trusted sites on the local server as well([settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-security-and-privacy-settings-for-internet-explorer-11-9528b011-664c-b771-d757-43a2b78b2afe))

[IESettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8AwR.png)

Comment: I added it via GPO more than a week ago. My Internet Option settings are grayed out, so I cannot check there. When I run rsop.msc, I do see it listed there as I expect it would.